# Cross distro showing [OK] and [failed] messaged

Tags: linux, shell

How can I show

[OK] in green {default success message}

and 
[failed] in red {default error message}

In Fedora I am using

action  command

but in ubuntu it is giving action  command not found.

How can I show these messages on all the envoirment in script file ?

Comment: Where do you want to show this? At boot time? In a terminal? Kernel output?

Comment: at terminal [ok] or [failed] based on my application return code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo -e Answering question.... '\e[00;32m'[OK]'\e[00m'
echo -e Back to work.... '\e[00;31m'[FAILED]'\e[00m'
```

Search for "ANSI colors" for more.

Comment: It don't work on ubuntu server 

echo -n "abc"
echo -e Answering question.... '\e[00;32m'[OK]'\e[00m'
 
It gives 

abc-e Answering question.... \e[00;32m[OK]\e[00m

Comment: @VivekGoel I don't have ubuntu, but did try it on my own distro. Are you sure you copy-pasted it ?

Comment: yes. on other distro it is working. Only I am getting that problem on ubuntu server.

Comment: @VivekGoel What terminal emulator are you using ?

Comment: ok. got the problem I was using sh filename.sh 
so it was not executing as bash.